# Getting body parameters in PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to fetch data sent in `body` of a request . I have tried using the `$_REQUEST[key]` variable but it seems to return empty.

Sample result of dumping the `$_REQUEST` variable via `print_r` is as follows:

```
[--123 Content-Disposition:_form-data;_name] => "theCustomers"

{
  "theCustomers" : [
    {
      "Customer" : {
        "AddressData" : [
          {
            "Address" : { ...................
}]}]
```

Any help is appreciated. There is another key that needs to be fetched but I have only posted one as the other should also be the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can file_get_contents the php://input

```
$input = file_get_contents('php://input');
$value = $json->decode($input);
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. but can you assist if we can get data via key/value pairs as some data in body is not json..

Comment: As far as I understand, if you are sending mixed data like that, it is a problem. You have to send the body all of one type I think. Other than that, you have to maybe do some custom parsing. But I have never come across this. How are you generating the input?

Comment: its sent by some other developers. just wanted to ask if its possible in some way to tell php to get $_REQUEST['theCustomers']  ?

Comment: ah, sorry. No. No that I know of.